# Enable gateway only for authenticated clients

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, authentication

I want my server to be usable as a gateway to the internet by certain clients. Enabling forwarding is not my concern, rather to restrict it only to certain clients.

I don't want hardcoded `iptables` rules which allow access from specified IP addresses because a machine in the network can claim any IP it wants.

What I am looking for is a way to authenticate a machine, then dynamically add a rule which grants its IP the right to redirect traffic through my server and maybe run a cron job every minute to check if IP address is still assigned to the same machine.

### **Idea**

My idea so far was to create a small website which authenticates the user (e.g. with tokens) and then use PHP's `exec` function to create the `iptables` rule. Only problem I have is to **securely** grant apache the right to `sudo`.

I found these two SO questions on that topic ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exec), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915241/how-to-run-from-php-a-bash-script-under-root-user)), both of whose answers, however, pose security issues (in my understanding).

Comment: What you're describing is essentially a Captive Portal. Surely there must be some products out there that you could use, instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: Sounds good, right now I'm having a look on [this](http://www.andybev.com/index.php/Using_iptables_and_PHP_to_create_a_captive_portal). I will be reporting here as soon as I have some results.

Comment: For the moment, I've settled with vigilem's answer. Since the question is put on-hold, I cannot give a detailed description of what I have done to achieve the goal. When I finally get the captive portal working as suggested by pauska, there may or may not be a Q&A about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler method would be to use mac authentication in iptables and skip the whole separate website piece. Granted, this does not dynamically add a rule so it may not be to your liking, but it would adequately allow access for only those users you desire. Of course, MAC spoofing is an official possibility, but if your users are that savvy/deceptive, you've got bigger problems.

Comment: The problem is that I am not the admin of the whole network, only of that gateway server, so I cannot control who is in the network.

Comment: Understood. I won't belabor the point, but if you have a fixed group of users you want to grant access *and* can get their MAC addresses, then you can do this without administrative control of the entire network. If the group of users constantly changes and the user requesting access has to authenticate from the client side, it sounds as if you're on the right track with your idea.

Comment: The group of users (and their MAC address) does not change indeed. But I am concerned about the MAC spoofing, since there might be a malicious user in the network.

Comment: Got it. Depending on your network's infrastructure, you may have protections in place at the switching layer to prevent spoofing - but your infrastructure/network staff can shed light on that situation.